# How can I pass map variable to Azure Devops pipeline job?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I'm learning Azure Devops pipelines, my first project is to create simple vnet with subnet using Terraform. I figured how to pass simple key-value variables, but problem is how to pass for example list of strings or more important, map variable from Terraform.

I'm using it to create subnets using each key - each value loop.

There are files that I'm using, I'm getting error about syntax in pipeline.yaml for VirtualNetworkAddressSpace and VirtualNetworkSubnets values.
Can you please help me with this one?

variables.tf

```
variable RG_Name {
    type = string
    #default = "TESTMS"
}

variable RG_Location {
    type = string
    #default = "West Europe"
}

variable VirtualNetworkName {
    type = string
    #default = "TESTSS"
}

variable VirtualNetworkAddressSpace {
    type = list(string)
    #default = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

variable VirtualNetworkSubnets {
    type = map
      #default = {
        #"GatewaySubnet" = "10.0.255.0/27"
  #}
}
```

dev.tfvars

```
RG_Name = __rgNAME__
RG_Location = __rgLOCATION__
VirtualNetworkName = __VirtualNetworkName__
VirtualNetworkAddressSpace = __VirtualNetworkAddressSpace__
VirtualNetworkSubnets = __VirtualNetworkSubnets__
```

pipeline.yaml

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    trigger:
    - feature/learning

stages:
  - stage: DEV
    jobs:
    - deployment: TERRAFORM
      displayName: 'Terraform deployment'
      pool:
        nvmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        workspace:
          clean: all
      variables:
        - name: 'rgNAME'
          value: 'skwiera-rg'
        - name: 'rgLOCATION'
          value: 'West Europe'
        - name: 'VirtualNetworkName'
          value: 'SkwieraVNET'
        - name: 'VirtualNetworkAddressSpace'
          value: ['10.0.0.0/16']
        - name: 'VirtualNetworkSubnets'
          value: {'GatewaySubnet' : '10.0.255.0/27'}
      environment: 'DEV'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - checkout: self
            - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
              displayName: 'Replace Terraform variables'
              inputs:
                  targetFiles: '**/*.tfvars'
                  tokenPrefix: '__'
                  tokenSuffix: '__'
            - task: TerraformInstaller@0
              displayName: "Install Terraform"
              inputs:
                terraformVersion: '1.0.8'
            - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
              displayName: 'Terraform Init'
              inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'init'
                backendServiceArm: 'skwieralearning'
                backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'skwiera-learning-rg'
                backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'skwieralearningtfstate'
                backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstate'
                backendAzureRmKey: 'dev.tfstate'
            - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
              displayName: 'Terraform Validate'
              inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'validate'
            - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
              displayName: "Terraform Plan"
              inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'plan'
                environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'skwieralearning'
            - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
              displayName: 'Terraform Apply'
              inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'apply'
                environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'skwieralearning'
```

Comment: What happens if you wrap the value in quotes so that it's a string in the YAML? eg `value: '{"GatewaySubnet" : "10.0.255.0/27"}'`

Comment: @ydaetskcoR That was exactly the case, turns out that both terraform and az pipeline is very sensitive about '' and "" types of quotes. By messing arround with them it finally works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [Azure Devops `pipeline.yaml` file is expecting the job variable's value to be a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#variables) but if you use:

```yaml
 - name: 'VirtualNetworkSubnets'
   value: {'GatewaySubnet' : '10.0.255.0/27'}
```

Then the YAML parser sees that as a nested mapping under the `value` key as [YAML supports both `key1: value` and `{key: value}` syntax for mappings](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#21-collections).

You can avoid it being read as a mapping by wrapping it in quotes so that it's read as a string literal:

```yaml
 - name: 'VirtualNetworkSubnets'
   value: "{'GatewaySubnet' : '10.0.255.0/27'}"
```

---

Separately you can avoid the `qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3` step and the tokenised values in `dev.tfvars` by [prefixing the environment variables with `TF_VAR_`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#environment-variables):

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: DEV
    jobs:
    - deployment: TERRAFORM
      displayName: 'Terraform deployment'
      pool:
        nvmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        workspace:
          clean: all
      variables:
        - name: 'TF_VAR_rgNAME'
          value: 'skwiera-rg'
        - name: 'TF_VAR_rgLOCATION'
          value: 'West Europe'
        - name: 'TF_VAR_VirtualNetworkName'
          value: 'SkwieraVNET'
        - name: 'TF_VAR_VirtualNetworkAddressSpace'
          value: "['10.0.0.0/16']"
        - name: 'TF_VAR_VirtualNetworkSubnets'
          value: "{'GatewaySubnet' : '10.0.255.0/27'}"
```